# Java, Return to a previous step in program upon user input

Tags: java

I have a program where the user is asked multiple choice questions and one of the choices to every question is to exit.

If exit is chosen, I then have to ask whether user wants to start again, if yes, I want to loop back to a certain checkpoint. If not, the program terminates.

Below is a simplified sample with only one question. The program I'm trying to build has multiple.

Is there a way that does not involve nested loop upon nested loops upon nested loops?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RandomStuff {
    
    /* this is not the actual program, just a simplified version to show what I'm trying to figure out
    let's pretend perfect input
    */
    
    public static void main (String[]args){
       
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     // checkpoint I wish to loop back to. Not the beginning of the program
     System.out.println("Press 1 to continue, press 2 to cancel ");
     int number = keyboard.nextInt();
     String again;
     
     switch(number){
     
    case 1:
   System.out.println("user chose to continue");
   
    break;
    
   case 2:
   System.out.println("user chose to cancel");
   System.out.println("start again? (yes/no)");
   again = keyboard.next();
   
   if("yes".equals(again)){
   /* loop to checkpoint*/ }
   
   else 
       System.exit(0);
    break;
         
     }
     
     /* afterwards, a few other rounds of asking an input an looping to the same checkpoint 
     when appropriate. Essentially I'm looking for a method to loop back to checkpoint
     from any decision to be made
     */
     
   
    keyboard.close();
}

    }
```

Comment: You can use [recursions](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_recursion.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use of recursive functions is the best alternative for loops. Instead of writing your choices in the main method you can use anther method like below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Random{
    
    public static void Choice(Scanner keyboard){
        
        System.out.println("Press 1 to continue, press 2 to cancel ");
        int number = keyboard.nextInt();
        String again;
     
        switch(number){
     
        case 1:
        System.out.println("user chose to continue");
        break;
    
        case 2:
        System.out.println("user chose to cancel");
        System.out.println("start again? (yes/no)");
        again = keyboard.next();
   
        if("yes".equals(again)){
            
                Choice(keyboard);
                //Function will be called again
            
            }
   
        else 
            System.exit(0);
            break;
         
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Choice(sc);
        
    }
    
}
```

But this can also easily be done with the use of a single do-while loop

See this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Random{
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean run = true;
        
        do{
            
            System.out.println("Press 1 to continue, press 2 to cancel ");
            int number = keyboard.nextInt();
            String again;
     
            switch(number){
     
            case 1:
                System.out.println("user chose to continue");
                break;
    
            case 2:
                System.out.println("user chose to cancel");
                System.out.println("start again? (yes/no)");
                again = keyboard.next();
    
                if("yes".equals(again)){
                    
                    continue;
                
                }
    
                else 
                    run = false;
                    //terimanting the loop
                    break;
         
           }
        }
        while(run);{
            System.out.println("User chose to exit"); 
            System.exit(0);  
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I tested both the programs and they run fine on my end, if you have any problem or you can't understand something, just tell me.

Comment: so followup: the function will go back using recursive and ask for an entry again but will not go back in the switch loop unless I explicitely ask it (I used a boolean and loop if boolean true, anyway). Maybe I implemented it wrong but a heads up for everyone else